# Access to environment variables by xaml code

Tags: wpf, xaml, environment-variables

It is possible to access somehow ONLY via xaml code to an environment variable?
In my case, I only need the read access.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write a custom markup extension. Something like:

```
[MarkupExtensionReturnType(typeof(String))]
public class EnvironmentVarExtension : MarkupExtension
{
    private string _variableName;

    public EnvironmentVarExtension(string variableName)
    {
        _variableName = variableName;
    }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        return Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(VariableName);
    }

    [ConstructorArgument("variableName")]
    public string VariableName
    {
        get { return _variableName; }
        set { _variableName = value; }
    }
}
```

And use it in your XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <TextBlock Text="{local:EnvironmentVar Path}" />
</Grid>
```